# How to rank with missing data?

Tags: missing-data, ranking

I have 180 subjects that I'd like to rank based on their performance in a variety of categories. However, not every subject is present in each category. Only one of the categories has every subject present while others have only 80, 50, or 10. Is there a reasonable way for me to rank these 180 subjects based on their overall performance across the categories?

I've read about several methods of imputation and weight revisions, but I am unsure what the best test would be.